# Selenium Web scraping nested divs with no ids or class names

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to get the product name and the quantity from a nested HTML table using selenium. My problem is some of the divs don't have any id or class names. The table I am trying to access is the **Critical Product list**. Here is what I have done but I do seem to be lost at how I can get the nested divs. *The site is in the code.*

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument('start-maximized')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'/usr/local/bin/chromedriver/')
url = 'https://www.rrpcanada.org/#/' # site I'm scraping
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(150)
page = driver.page_source
driver.quit()


html_soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
item_containers = html_soup.find_all('div', class_='critical-products-title hide-mobile')

if item_containers:
    for item in item_containers:
       for link in item.findAll('a', ) # need to loop the inner divs to reach the href and then get to the left and right classes to get title and quantity
        print(item)
```

Here is the image from the inspection. I want to be able to loop through all the divs and get the title and quantity.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You don't need beautiful soup, nor to save the page_source.
I used a CSS selector to select all the target rows in the table and then applied list comprehension to choose the left and right sides of each row. I outputted the results to a list of tuples.

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument('start-maximized')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'/usr/local/bin/chromedriver/')
url = 'https://www.rrpcanada.org/#/' # site I'm scraping
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(150)

elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#app > div:nth-child(1) > div.header-wrapper > div.header-right > div.critical-product-table-container > div.table.shorten.hide-mobile > div > div > div > a > div')

targetted_values = [(element.find_element_by_css_selector('.line-item-left').text, element.find_element_by_css_selector('.line-item-right').text) for element in elements]

driver.quit()
```

Example output of targetted_values:

```
[('Surgical & Reusable Masks', '376,713,363 available'),
('Disposable Gloves', '66,962,093 available'),
('Gowns and Coveralls', '40,502,145 available'),
('Respirators', '22,189,273 available'),
('Surface Wipes', '20,650,831 available'),
('Face Shields', '16,535,686 available'),
('Hand Sanitizer', '11,152,890 L available'),
('Thermometers', '8,457,993 available'),
('Testing Kits', '2,110,815 available'),
('Surface Solutions', '107,452 L available'),
('Protective Barriers', '10,833 available'),
('Ventilators', '410 available')]
```

Comment: How are you getting the output? When I put print statement, I don't get anything in return

Comment: @Saad Everything is stored in targetted_values. Try print(targetted_values)

Answer (score 1):

To print the product name and the quantity you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.rrpcanada.org/#/')
  items =  [my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.table.shorten.hide-mobile > div div.line-item-title")))]
  quantities =  [my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.table.shorten.hide-mobile > div div.line-item-bold.available")))]
  for i,j in zip(items,quantities):
    print(i, j)
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.rrpcanada.org/#/')
  items =  [my_elem.get_attribute("innerHTML") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='table shorten hide-mobile']/div//div[@class='line-item-title']")))]
  quantities =  [my_elem.get_attribute("innerHTML") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='table shorten hide-mobile']/div//div[@class='line-item-bold available']")))]
  for i,j in zip(items,quantities):
    print(i, j)
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Surgical &amp; Reusable Masks  376,713,363 available
  Disposable Gloves  66,962,093 available
  Gowns and Coveralls  40,502,145 available
  Respirators  22,189,273 available
  Surface Wipes  20,650,831 available
  Face Shields  16,535,686 available
  Hand Sanitizer  11,152,890 L available
  Thermometers  8,457,993 available
  Testing Kits  2,110,815 available
  Surface Solutions  107,452 L available
  Protective Barriers  10,833 available
  Ventilators  410 available
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55240245/how-to-retrieve-the-text-of-a-webelement-using-selenium-python/55241232#55241232)

---

### Outro

Link to useful documentation:

- [`get_attribute()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method `Gets the given attribute or property of the element.`
- [`text`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) attribute returns `The text of the element.`
- [Difference between text and innerHTML using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416048/difference-between-text-and-innerhtml-using-selenium/55902072#55902072)

Comment: Which one is considered best practice?

Comment: @Saad _best practice_ in terms of?

Comment: Best practice in terms of reliability and scalability.

Comment: @Saad IMO _reliability and scalability_ is related to framework. However, locating strategies should be canonical be it a _xpath_ or a _cssSelector_. Hence was my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use relative xpath to find the element with `class="line-item-left"` for the name of each item and the element with `class="line-item-right"` for the number of available items.

```
driver.find_elements_by_class_name("line-item-left") //Item names
driver.find_elements_by_class_name("line-item-right") //Number of items available
```

Note the 's' in element**s**

Answer (score 0):

This is the selector for **`product name`**:

```
div.critical-product-table-container div.line-item-left
```

And for **`total`**:

```
div.critical-product-table-container div.line-item-right
```

But the following approach is without `BeautifulSoup`.

`time.sleep(...)` is bad practice, please use [**`WebDriverWait`**](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) instead.

And to pair the above two variables and perform parallel looping, I try to use the [**`zip()`**](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) function:

```
url = 'https://www.rrpcanada.org/#/' # site I'm scraping
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 150)
product_names = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.critical-product-table-container div.line-item-left')))
totals = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.critical-product-table-container div.line-item-right')))

for product_name, total in zip(product_names, totals):
    print(product_name.text +'--' +total.text)
    
driver.quit()
```

You need following import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```